# Can't Move File After Changing Permissions

Tags: 16.04, permissions, chmod, chown

I have a folder located in `/var/www` that I am trying to move to my user's home directory.

I initially ran `mv folder/ ~`, and received a permissions denied error. I thought I had set the permissions up correctly, but to be sure I ran `sudo chown -R folder/ user` where user was my current user. I then ran `chmod -R u=rwx folder/` to give myself write and read permissions (or whatever `mv` might require). However,  even after trying to run `mv` again, I still lacked permissions.

What might cause this?

Full log of me repeating the above process:

```
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root      4096 Mar 18 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root      root      4096 Mar 18 10:13 ..
drwx------  4 webserver webserver 4096 Mar 18 10:44 website
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ sudo chown -R webserver website/
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root      4096 Mar 18 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root      root      4096 Mar 18 10:13 ..
drwx------  4 webserver webserver 4096 Mar 18 10:44 website
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ chmod -R 700 website/
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root      4096 Mar 18 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root      root      4096 Mar 18 10:13 ..
drwx------  4 webserver webserver 4096 Mar 18 10:44 website
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ mv website/ ~
mv: cannot move 'website/' to '/home/webserver/website': Permission denied
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$
```

**Edit:** Interestingly enough, when I tried to move subdirectories and files individually it succeeded without any problems:

```
webserver@testingweb:/var/www$ cd website/
webserver@testingweb:/var/www/website$ ls
git  reproot
webserver@testingweb:/var/www/website$ mv git/ ~/website/
webserver@testingweb:/var/www/website$ ls
reproot
webserver@testingweb:/var/www/website$ mv reproot/ ~/website/
webserver@testingweb:/var/www/website$ ls
webserver@testingweb:/var/www/website$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have write permissions over `/var/www/website`, but you don't have write permission over `/var/www`. 
In order to move `/var/www/website` to anywhere you need write permission over `/var/www`.

Comment: (+1) That makes sense, thank you